# Phprunner - edit selected records

Tags: php, parameter-passing, multi-select

I have an app that is being developed via phprunner.
It has to do with product deliveries.

I need to edit multiple records and update a field of them with the same value.

The table is called 'product_deliveries' and it has 4 columns (id, product_id, surname, name).

I want to select 2-3 records(product_deliveries) and open a pop up window where the user fills the name and the surname of the recipient.

So I added a button in the list page, called "multiple delivery" and a custom view ot the above table with the 2 fields to be filled.

In the 'server tab' of the button I wrote:

```
global $dal;
$_SESSION["selection"]s = array();
while ($data = $button->getNextSelectedRecord() ) 
{
$_SESSION["selection"] = $keys;
}
```

and in the 'before record updated' event of the custom view

```
global $dal;
for ($i=0;$i<count($_REQUEST["selection"]);$i++ )
{
$sql = "Update product_deliveries set name=".$values['name']." where id="         .$_REQUEST["selection"][$i]["ID"];
CustomQuery($sql);
}
```

BUT as a result, I am getting all the records updated and not just the selected ones.

How can I pass the selected records to the custom view edit page?

Could you help me?
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

i found this Question not answered, while search for solution on phprunner help doc, and i hope it will help you or someone.

1st to access the list of selected values
you can use the below loop on server side tab

```
while($record = $button->getNextSelectedRecord()) {

}
```

and inside this loop you can insert any query you want as custom query, or use builtin [PHPrunner Data Access Layer values](https://xlinesoft.com/phprunner/docs/data_access_layer.htm)

```
$sql = "update product_deliveries set name=" .$record["name"]." where
id=" .$record["ID"]; CustomQuery($sql);
```

this is worked fine at my end, and hope it work fine for you too

and [here the more of Insert button examples](https://xlinesoft.com/phprunner/docs/inserting_button.htm)